# Can't install Python mysqlclient bindings

Tags: python, mysql

I'm running 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04. Although I got it working on my work machine (Ubuntu 18.10 64 bit), I simply *cannot* get the MySQL client Python libraries working on my personal machine. It's [well-documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface) online that you have to install it "twice": once with `pip` (the Python bindings) and once with `apt` (the actual C library). I've just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu, and executed:

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
pip install mysqlclient
```

I've tried this with both python 2 and python 3 virtualenvs, and I get the same error in both cases:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/home/jack/Code/Skylights/Operator/Env3/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:37:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```